# SSRS & SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sql-server

Does SSRS need to be installed on a separate server in a SharePoint 2013 production Farm?

If so what are the licensing implications for SQL Server?

Answer (score 3):

**Does SSRS need to be installed on a separate server in a SharePoint 2013 production Farm?**

- From `Performance` perspective , it's recommended to install `SSRS SharePoint integrated mode` to a sperate SharePoint server then join it to the farm.
- From `Design` Perspective , `SSRS SharePoint integrated Mode` must be installed on the server that has SharePoint.
- From `Cost` Perspective , you can install it on the current SharePoint Servers and scale up the servers specification to avoid the performance issue rather than scale out a new server with an additional SharePoint License that leads to additional cost.

**What are the licensing implications for SQL Server?**

It's excluded from `DB installation license` and it requires `SSRS SQL Server license` on your SharePoint Server.

Answer (score 2):

From a performance perspective, ideally SSRS runs on one or more FEs. This prevents user requests to SSRS from leaving the SharePoint FE. This may increase system requirements on the FE, however.

From a licensing perspective, you must license each SSRS instance installed with a SQL Server BI User CALs or SQL Server Enterprise CAL. This means if you have a SQL Server Database Engine for SharePoint on SQLSERVER1, an SSRS integrated with SharePoint on SPSERVER1 and SPSERVER2, you would need 3 SQL Server licenses.